# Azure AD-B2C error: IDX10501: Signature validation failed. Unable to match keys: kid: '[PII is hidden]', token: '[PII is hidden]'

Tags: oauth-2.0, openid-connect, azure-ad-b2c

I’m using Swagger to make API calls, for authentication I’m able to generate Bearer token but after that I' m getting 401 in response. After checking logs, below is the error:

```
Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SecurityTokenSignatureKeyNotFoundException: IDX10501: Signature validation failed. Unable to match keys: 
kid: '[PII is hidden]', 
token: '[PII is hidden]'
```

My ConfigureAuth method is as below:

```cs
private static void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
{
    var metadataEndpoint = string.Format(
        configProvider.GetConfigValue<string>("ida:AadInstance", "AuthConfig"),
        configProvider.GetConfigValue<string>("ida:Tenant", "AuthConfig"),
        configProvider.GetConfigValue<string>("ida:SignInPolicy", "AuthConfig"));

    string[] validAudiences = configProvider.GetConfigValue<string>("ida:Audiences", "AuthConfig").Split(',');
    TokenValidationParameters tvps = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        ValidAudiences = validAudiences,
        AuthenticationType = configProvider.GetConfigValue<string>("ida:SignInPolicy", "AuthConfig"),
        ValidateAudience = true,
        ValidateIssuer = configProvider.GetConfigValue<bool>("validateIssuer", "AuthConfig"),
        ValidateLifetime = true,
        ValidAudience = configProvider.GetConfigValue<string>("Swagger:ClientId", "AuthConfig"),
        //NameClaimType = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/objectidentifier",
    };

    //SecurityToken securityToken;
    //JwtSecurityTokenHandler handler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
    app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(
        new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions
         {
            AccessTokenFormat = new JwtFormat(tvps, new OpenIdConnectCachingSecurityTokenProvider(metadataEndpoint)),
            Provider = new OAuthBearerAuthenticationProvider()
            {
                OnRequestToken = (context) =>
                {
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(context.Token))
                    {
                    }

                    return Task.FromResult<int>(0);
                },
                OnValidateIdentity = (context) =>
                    {
                        ////TO DO
                        //// Steps to perform after identity validation

                        return Task.FromResult<int>(0);
                    }
            }
        });
}
```

Comment: Who is generating your JWTs?

Comment: The error is saying ‘the OpenID Connect endpoint does not have the key  used to sign that JWT so I can’t validate it’

Comment: JWT token will be generated from AD B2C.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was able to validate the token by passing the correct metadata endpoint.
*

> https://login.microsoftonline.com/tfp/{0}/{1}/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration

*

Comment: Can you source that?

Comment: Sorry didn't understand , do you want me to put the complete code here ?

Comment: Hi  Rumpi - no, just how you figured that out?  I assume some webpage?

Comment: Hi, sorry I didn't get that in some web page, the security consultant in my team figured it out.

Comment: I also had to update `TokenValidationParameters.ValidAudience`

Answer (score 6):

I had to update my OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions.MetadataAddress to 
https://login.microsoftonline.com/tfp/{tenantId}/{policyId}/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this is the same message that will be reported when the issuer signs the token with an algorithm other than RSA.  Apparently ECDSA will be available soon:
https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-identitymodel-extensions-for-dotnet/issues/487