# How to validate token

Tags: azure

I have integrated Azure AD with my application. Now, I want to use the following code to validate token. But, when I validate Microsoft graph token, I get an error : IDX10501: Signature validation failed. Unable to match key.

My code

```
public JwtSecurityToken Validate(string token)
        {
            string stsDiscoveryEndpoint = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration";

            ConfigurationManager<OpenIdConnectConfiguration> configManager = new ConfigurationManager<OpenIdConnectConfiguration>(stsDiscoveryEndpoint, new OpenIdConnectConfigurationRetriever());

            OpenIdConnectConfiguration config = configManager.GetConfigurationAsync().Result;

            TokenValidationParameters validationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                ValidateAudience = false,
                ValidateIssuer = false,
                IssuerSigningKeys = config.SigningKeys,
                ValidateLifetime = false
            };

            JwtSecurityTokenHandler tokendHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();

            SecurityToken jwt;

            var result = tokendHandler.ValidateToken(token, validationParameters, out jwt);

            return jwt as JwtSecurityToken;
        }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51221979/azure-ad-b2c-error-idx10501-signature-validation-failed-unable-to-match-keys

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this issue, make sure that the algorithm for the JWT matches with the configuration of your middleware.

Refer to this [article](https://developer.okta.com/code/dotnet/jwt-validation/) and change `configurationManager` as below:

```
var issuer = "https://https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/v2.0";

var configurationManager = new ConfigurationManager<OpenIdConnectConfiguration>(
    issuer + "/.well-known/oauth-authorization-server",
    new OpenIdConnectConfigurationRetriever());
```

Comment: It does not work. When I run the code ```OpenIdConnectConfiguration config = configManager.GetConfigurationAsync().Result;```, I get the error : InvalidOperationException: IDX20803: Unable to obtain configuration from: '[PII is hidden]'.

Comment: Where do I need to add the code ```System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol |= SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;```?