# Receiving the error message of IDX10501: Signature validation failed. Unable to match keys when using Azure AD

Tags: authentication, asp.net-core, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

**Just a heads up:** this question is not a duplicate of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51221979/azure-ad-b2c-error-idx10501-signature-validation-failed-unable-to-match-keys), so please do not mark this question as a duplicate.

I scaffolded a web api code that uses Azure Active Directory for authentication by Visual Studio 2019 and followed [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/bs-latn-ba/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-protected-web-api-app-configuration) to configure the basic scaffolded application by using the configuration entries of my Azure AD B2C tenant.

The service configuration method looks like the following code snippet:

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
   Microsoft.IdentityModel.Logging.IdentityModelEventSource.ShowPII = true;
            services
                .AddAuthentication(AzureADDefaults.BearerAuthenticationScheme)
                .AddAzureADBearer(options => Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options));
            services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
}
```

The configuration file contains the following AzureAd configuraiton entry where I masked the actual Ids:

```
  "AzureAd": {
    "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
    "Domain": "testdirectoryv44.onmicrosoft.com",
    "TenantId": "1234abcdef......,
    "ClientId": "abcdef567....."   
  }
```

By running the userflow on the Azure portal, I obtain a token and am able to decode the token by https://jwt.ms which is great. However, I receive the following error message when calling this GET request: `https://localhost:44362/api/values` by POSTMAN while it is including the bearer token in the header when placing the request: (The error message is shown in the output pane of VS 2019)

> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerHandler:Information:
>   Failed to validate the token.
>
> Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SecurityTokenSignatureKeyNotFoundException:
>   IDX10501: Signature validation failed. Unable to match keys:  kid:
>   'ABCDEF.........',  token:
>   '{"typ":"JWT","alg":"RS256","kid":"ABCDEF........."}.{"exp":1572358190,"nbf":1572354590,"ver":"1.0","iss":"https://testdirectoryv44.b2clogin.com/abcdef1234556/v2.0/","sub":"8799abcdef0000","aud":"89000abcdecf999,"nonce":"defaultNonce","iat":1572354590,"auth_time":1572354590,"idp_access_token":"BIGMASKEDVALUE","idp":"https://sts.windows.net/abcdef11234.../","name":"MyName","extension_InternalKey":"KEY400","given_name":"MyName","family_name":"MyFamily","extension_InternalUserId":"guest","tfp":"B2C_1_testdirectoryv44"}'.
>   at
>   System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.JwtSecurityTokenHandler.ValidateSignature(String
>   token, TokenValidationParameters validationParameters)    at
>   System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.JwtSecurityTokenHandler.ValidateToken(String
>   token, TokenValidationParameters validationParameters, SecurityToken&
>   validatedToken)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerHandler.HandleAuthenticateAsync()
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerHandler:Information:
>   AzureADJwtBearer was not authenticated. Failure message: IDX10501:
>   Signature validation failed. Unable to match keys:  kid:
>   'REMOVED AREAD'.
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware:Information: Executing
>   endpoint 'WebApplication5.Controllers.ValuesController.Get
>   (WebApplication5)'
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker:Information:
>   Route matched with {action = "Get", controller = "Values"}. Executing
>   controller action with signature
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ActionResult`1[System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.String]]
>   Get() on controller WebApplication5.Controllers.ValuesController
>   (WebApplication5).
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.DefaultAuthorizationService:Information:
>   Authorization failed.
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker:Information:
>   Authorization failed for the request at filter
>   'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Authorization.AuthorizeFilter'.
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ChallengeResult:Information: Executing
>   ChallengeResult with authentication schemes ().
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerHandler:Information:
>   AuthenticationScheme: AzureADJwtBearer was challenged.
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker:Information:
>   Executed action WebApplication5.Controllers.ValuesController.Get
>   (WebApplication5) in 22.7988ms
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware:Information: Executed
>   endpoint 'WebApplication5.Controllers.ValuesController.Get
>   (WebApplication5)'
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost:Information: Request
>   finished in 792.0596ms 401

The Web api's code is as simple as the following code snippet which is scaffolded by Visual Studio 2019:

```cs
[Authorize]
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class ValuesController : ControllerBase
    {
        // GET api/values
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult<IEnumerable<string>> Get()
        {
            return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
        }

        // GET api/values/5
        [HttpGet("{id}")]
        public ActionResult<string> Get(int id)
        {
            return "value";
        }

        // POST api/values
        [HttpPost]
        public void Post([FromBody] string value)
        {
            // For more information on protecting this API from Cross Site Request Forgery (CSRF) attacks, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=717803
        }

        // PUT api/values/5
        [HttpPut("{id}")]
        public void Put(int id, [FromBody] string value)
        {
            // For more information on protecting this API from Cross Site Request Forgery (CSRF) attacks, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=717803
        }

        // DELETE api/values/5
        [HttpDelete("{id}")]
        public void Delete(int id)
        {
            // For more information on protecting this API from Cross Site Request Forgery (CSRF) attacks, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=717803
        }
    }
```

It's been a couple of days that I have been spending time on figuring out the root cause of this failure but no success so far. What point am I missing in the code or in Azure AD configuration causing this issue and why https://jwt.ms is able to decode the token successfully?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please note that Azure AD is different from Azure AD B2C.

The service configuration method

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddAuthentication(AzureADB2CDefaults.BearerAuthenticationScheme)
        .AddAzureADB2CBearer(options => Configuration.Bind("AzureAdB2C", options));
    services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
}
```

appsettings.json

```
{
  "AzureAdB2C": {
    "Instance": "https://tony**test.b2clogin.com/tfp/",
    "ClientId": "5eaf724c-a61e-***-a217-44ffd45f9dfe",
    "Domain": "tony**test.onmicrosoft.com",
    "SignUpSignInPolicyId": "B2C_1_testsignupin"
  },
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

You can follow this detailed [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-tutorials-web-api).

Comment: I wish Microsoft's AD documentation team could have documented all steps including your answer more properly. Thanks for your help, @Tony Ju.

Comment: Why do you specify the signupplicy? surely it doesnt use that policy to verify the bearer token,